# How to make command with included current working directory name, but not full path

Tags: command-line, git

Since im making my forks called as folders im using them then for fast push wanted to make command

```
git commit -a && git push origin printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}" && git fetch --all
```

Somehow its not working. How to make any command in command?

Answer (score 3):

```
git push origin printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}"
```

That `printf` is going to be taken literally by the command. It needs to be run before the git statement. You can do this by either setting it to a variable beforehand (or more commonly) wrapping it:

```
git push origin $(printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`basename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/basename.1) as,

```
git push origin $(basename ${PWD})
```

or,

```
git push origin `basename ${PWD}`
```